# TCP: правда ли, что send/write нельзя вызывать из разных потоков, иначе перепутается содержимое буферов?

Tags: c#, c++, многопоточность, tcp-ip, сокеты

Я строю довольно сложную клиент-серверную систему, поэтому хотелось бы иметь возможность применить многопоточность, скажем на клиенте в одном потоке отправлять heartbeat, а в другом - команду серверу, и при этом использовать только один сокет.
Но нормальное ли это решение?

Для начала поясню, о какой именно путанице я говорю.

Итак, псевдокод то что я отправляю:

```
send("123456"); // Поток 1
send("ABCDEF");  // Поток 2
```

Я знаю, что в итоге на принимающую сторону может прийти вот такое:

```
ABCDEF
123456
```

То есть **я понимаю, что может перепутаться порядок самих сообщений**, которые я отправляю.
Когда я попробовал создать много потоков, **я наблюдал такое**, значит это действительно так.
И я этого не боюсь.

---

Но один человек на форуме, если я его правильно понял, утверждает, что все еще хуже.
**Говорит, что якобы могут перепутаться сами байты в сообщениях**, то есть может прийти и такое:

```
ABC45F
123DE6
```

Правда ли это?
Когда я пробовал создать много потоков, то **этого я НЕ наблюдал**, сообщений было много, но ни в одном из них байты не смешивались с байтами из других сообщений.
Но не буду надеяться на авось, вот на всякий случай спрашиваю.

**Операционная система**:
Windows, разных версий и разрядностей, но только Windows, и на сервере и на клиентах.

Comment: Можно было бы добавить ссылку, где кто это говорит.

Comment: Скорее всего, это будет написано в документации к классу, который вы используете как обёртку к сокету. Обычно о недопущении одновременного использования должны позаботиться именно вы.

Comment: @VladD в классах-то что? просто тупая обертка для системной функции send, поэтому я и написал "send/write". меня интересует send, если она не смешивает байты, то и в классах .NET и т.д. тоже не будут смешиваться

Comment: @Qwertiy да я уже разбираю полеты с ним лично. может просто недопонимание возникло. на это больше похоже

Comment: @KG: Ну, а почему вы уверены, что это тупая обёртка? С другой стороны, если вы и правда уверены, ну так смотрите документацию к функции `send`.

Comment: @VladD я уверен, потому что у .NET открытый исходный код и потому что у меня еще и отладчик есть, который отслеживает вызовы системных функций. Да и по внешнему поведению ясно, что никакой новой логики эта обертка не привносит.

Comment: @VladD в документации написано:<br>send should not be called on the same stream-oriented socket concurrently from different threads,
because some Winsock providers may split a large send request into multiple transmissions,
and this may lead to unintended data interleaving from multiple concurrent send requests on
the same stream-oriented socket.<br>Но непонятно, что именно перепутается - отправленные буфера, сегменты или байты в 1 сегменте. Отправленные буфера - нормально, сегменты - кое-как сойдет (у меня малые объемы данных) а если байты в 1 сегменте - то катастрофа.

Comment: @Qwertiy вот ссылка на того, кто это говорит. http://cyberforum.ru/win-api/thread1856826-page3.html#post9881925 Он по-прежнему на этом настаивает. Это не недопонимание.

Comment: @KG: То, что в конце-концов вызовется send, это понятно. Но вы-то утверждаете намного больше: вы утверждаете, что в вызове из .NET _больше нет ничего, кроме передачи параметров в `send`_. Вы можете показать в исходниках на sourceof.net, где именно там просто прямой вызов, без синхронизации, буферизации и тому подобных штук?

Comment: @KG: Ну и в конце-концов, если вам пишут открытым текстом, что писать в один сокет из разных потоков **нельзя**, почему вы пытаетесь выяснить, а вдруг именно в вашем случае можно? Неужели так сложно замаршаллировать всё в один поток через async/await?

Comment: @VladD исходный код, конечно, смотрел пока только поверхностно... На чистом Си, напрямую с send, пока не пробовал... Насчет решения проблемы, еще вот мьютексы предлагают... Но вот нет опыта в многопоточности.

Comment: @KG: А зачем на чистом C? Если вас просят писать в сокет из одного потока, ну так пишите из одного. Это можно делать хоть на C#, хоть на C.

Comment: *не отвечая на сам вопрос*: вам не нужно это делать в разных тредах, single writer-системы практически всегда демонстрируют лучшую производительность и понятность разработчику. сделайте очередь, которую будет читать некоторый socket-writer, в любом случае ваша конечная цель - последовательная передача разных пакетов в сокет, и эту задачу как таковую не распраллелить (потому что она предполагает эту самую последовательную передачу).

Comment: @Etki Где будет лучше понятность - это вопрос, но вполне возможно. что именно в single writer. Собственно, у меня есть сообщения с полезными данными, а есть сообщения heartbeat (велосипед-keepalive), heartbeat отправляется каждые N сек (вернее, если пришел ответ сервера на этот heartbeat, то система ждет N сек и шлет новый), а полезные - в произвольное время, когда пользователь нажмет кнопку, и на них тоже ответ сервера. Ответы обрабатываются в одном и том же потоке, в одном и том же методе, там while и TCP'овский recv/read.

Comment: Строго говоря, вам не нужно слать heartbeat, пока у вас пересылаются полезные данные. Heartbeat у вас должен слаться в случае, если участник соединения простаивает N времени, а "живость" противоположного участника стоит определять просто по времени последнего пришедшего сообщеня. heartbeat'ы в этом случае вырождаются просто в NOOP-сообщения. В карйнем случае, у вас может быть priority queue на отправку данных.

Comment: @Etki ну это-то да, пока пересылаются данные - heartbeat не нужен, но так с непривычки сложно представить весь этот алгоритм с очередями и т.п., многопоточность как-то проще представить, отправляем данные и отправляем heatbeat, получаем два ответа - на heatbeat и на данные и обрабатываем каждый, а если вместо одного из ответов не приходит ничего (либо выбрасывается Exception), то прекращаем всю деятельность и вызываем tryConnect чтобы повторно подключиться.

Answer (score 3):

Вам не нужна для этого многопоточность, если вы просто воспользуетесь `async/await`. При этом все сообщения будут отправляться в одном потоке. Выглядит это как-то так:

```
AsyncLock socketLock = new AsyncLock();
async Task SendData(byte[] data, CancelltionToken ct)
{
    using (await socketLock.LockAsync(ct))
        await networkStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length, ct);
}

async Task SendHeartbeat(CancelltionToken ct)
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), ct);
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRrequested();
            await SendData(heartbitBytes, ct);
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCancelledException)
    {
    }
}
```

Ну и отправка обычного сообщения просто:

```
await SendData(messageBytes, ct);
```

В итоге мы обошлись без многопоточности.

Класс `AsyncLock` брать здесь: https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLock

---

По сути вопроса: если документация уж говорит, что в сокет/NetworkStream/что угодно нельзя писать из двух потоков одновременно, то лучше не пытаться выяснять, при каких условиях это ограничение можно обойти, потому что в следующей версии языка/библиотек такой хак может и не сработать. Оставайтесь на светлой стороне силы!

Comment: В следующей версии ОС тогда уж. А так спасибо, но какой-то сторонний класс для такой ерунды... Лучше сам реализую, даже без async await, мне еще и на Delphi 7 переписывать клиент, где нет никаких async await, это на сервере можно и C# и даже .NET 4...

Comment: @KG: Ну, а как вы руками забабахаете асинхронную блокировку? Это нетривиально.

Comment: @KG: А почему в следующей версии ОС? У вас XP, что ли? Начиная с семёрки, должно прекрасно идти.

Comment: да не знаю я пока как я ее забабахаю, не обязательно заморачиваться, можно просто сделать событие в потоке "writer" и вызывать его из других потоков. Насчет следующей версии, оооох... ну ясно же, что я имел в виду к слову "потому что в следующей версии языка/библиотек такой хак может и не сработать.", так вот не языка а ОС, какой вы нудный право

Comment: @KG: Ну, если вы думаете легко обойтись событием, удачи. Ну и возможно найдётся менее нудный объясняющий.